# How to pre-populate vimeo password protected video in the website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vimeo

in vimeo account we have video with "Only people with a password can see this video" we need to pre-populate password in web site with knowing the login user

attached image below

[vimeo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vckdd.png)

any one have any idea how to pre-populate vimeo password in website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-populating the password field isn't possible - if you're providing the password for a video at the prompt, what's the point of password protection?

You'll want to look at other privacy settings for your embedded videos, such as "Hide from vimeo.com" privacy and "Only on domains I choose" embed privacy. This way, the video will not be playable on vimeo.com/[video_id], and can only play on the domains you provide.

Vimeo Privacy FAQ here: https://vimeo.com/s/teg

Comment: I have a same question, I have a list of Vimeo videos with password, it's annoying to punch in passwords for each 5 mins videos. it would be great if i can embed a link with password